# property 'description' will not synthesize property

Tags: objective-c, exception, properties, read-write

I have this code, in some .h file:

```
@interface StatusData :JSONModel <NSCoding>
@property (strong, nonatomic)NSString <Optional> *description;
@end
```

and I got this warning:

> Auto property synthesis will not synthesize property 'description'
> because it is 'readwrite' but it will be synthesized 'readonly' via
> another property

which gives me exception in runtime:

---

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
> 'NSInvalidArgumentException',
>
> reason: '-[< ClassName> setDescription:]:
> unrecognized selector sent to instance

---

is there a way to override the '**description**' property to be readwrite ?

Answer (score 1):

'description' is a `readonly` property of `NSObject`:

```
@property (readonly, copy) NSString *description; (line 43)
```

**change the property name** to something else - That was the easiest solution for avoiding exception.

Anyway, that was only a work-around solution for now until I find a way to override the description property.

Comment: Why do you want to override the `description` property of `NSObject`? I'd recommend having a read of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5650887/whats-the-harm-of-property-override-in-objective-c to see when it's best to override a property and when it's best to just override it's getter and setter. Personally based on what I see I see no reason for you to override this property and would recommend just using a different property name.

Comment: @Popeye thanks for your response. I'll check overriding the setter.
basically you are right - choosing a different name is best, but in this case it's a field that comes from the server in a json, and I transform it to a class...